# Changing Data Types of Columns in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

This is how the df looks:

```
User-ID          ISBN Book-Rating Book-Title Book-Author    
1  "276725"  "034545104X"       "0"\\n        NaN         NaN  
2  "276726"  "0155061224"       "5"\\n        NaN         NaN  
Year-Of-Publication Publisher  
1                 NaN       NaN  
2                 NaN       NaN
```

with datatypes:

```
User-ID                object
Location               object
Age                    object
ISBN                   object
Book-Rating            object
Book-Title             object
Book-Author            object
Year-Of-Publication    object
Publisher              object
dtype: object
```

`.astype()` doesnt work for example as applied to `User-ID`:

```
df_final\["User-ID"\] = df_final\["User-ID"\].astype(int)
the error: i
nvalid literal for int() with base 10: '"1"'
```

So I tried creating functions to get rid of characters such as: `"`
The functions:

```
def convert_ID(val):
print(val)

    if type(val) == 'str':
            val = val.strip('\"')
        return int(val)
    
    def covert_rating(val):
         new_val = val.replace('\n"','')
    return int(new_val)
    
    def covert_ISBN(val):
         new_val = val.replace('\n"','')
    return int(new_val)
```

After passing: `df_final['User-ID'] = df_final['User-ID'].apply(convert_ID)`
I got the following error: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"1"'`

I guess I am not removing the quotes characters correctly.
How should the method(s) look like?
Also is it possible to store ISBN in a numeric value while keeping the startin 0?

I tried the different self-defined methods and `.astype()` method with no success

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you considered approaching it from the other direction? Instead of filtering out the characters you don't want, use .str.extract('(\d*)') to only include numbers.

Comment: Thank you @Linden that is smart and it worked!!!

Comment: @Linden who can, if I can, use the expression: .str.extract('(\d*)' for strings
say the string is: ""Book-Title"" and I want to just get: Book-Title
I guess the 'd' stands for digit, so I tried 's' for string but got KeyError: 'Book-Title'

Comment: Have a look at how to write regular expressions for python. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html. (The character to match any alphanumeric character (letters, numbers and underscores) is \w.)